# Counting specify value across columns in r

Tags: r

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
v1    v2    v3
pos   neg    pos
pos   pos    pos
neg   neg    neg
```

I want to create another column which has the winner between other three columns

```
v1    v2    v3    v4
pos   neg   pos   pos
pos   pos   pos   pos 
neg   neg   neg   neg
```

Comment: Are this character vectors, or actual numbers?

Comment: What does a "winner" mean? the majority?

Comment: Winner is the  value with majority. eg. if there are two 'pos' and one 'neg' the winner will be 'pos'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
mydf$v4 <- apply(mydf, 1, function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
   v1  v2  v3  v4
1 pos neg pos pos
2 pos pos pos pos
3 neg neg neg neg
```

Answer (score 4):

As "winner" means the majority, the following will work:

```
df$v4 <- ifelse(rowMeans(df == "neg") > 0.5, "neg", "pos")

df$v4
[1] "pos" "pos" "neg"
```

This uses `rowMeans` to calculate the proportion of elements in each row that are "neg". This result is fed to `ifelse` where if the proportion is greater than 0.5 in a row, then "neg" is returned, otherwise, "pos" is returned.

Note that the columns must be character. That's why I use the `as.is = TRUE` argument below.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "v1    v2    v3
pos   neg    pos
pos   pos    pos
neg   neg    neg", as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is not such a generalized solution though, as you are assuming: 1: you know all the possible values. 2: there are only 2 values possible in each row.

Comment: Didn't mean to imply anything about generalizability.